# How to produce an N-dimensional *direct* basis?

Tags: geometry, orthonormal, orientation

I need a procedure to generate an N-dimensional orthonormal direct basis.
The 1D, 2D, and 3D case are not a problem. For example, in the 3D case, if I have 3 vectors $v1, v2, v3$ (suppose they behave well i.e. no collinear vectors etc.) I can construct a basis with $u_1 = v_1/\|v_1\|$, $v_2 = [-{u_1}_{,2}; {u_1}_{,1}; 0]$ and $u_3 = u_1$ $\times$ $u_2$ (where $\times$ is the cross product).
My question is how to generalize this for any dimension?
I am aware that I could just generate N random vectors and apply gram-schmidt orthogonalization, but as far as I understand that does not guarantee me a direct basis (by direct I mean its orientation should be anti-clockwise in 2D --- not sure how the notion of orientation generalizes for higher dimensions).

Comment: The concept of [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(vector_space)) generalises to an equivalence relation on the set of ordered bases, with two equivalence classes. The upshot is that any vector space $V$ has two orientations, any ordered basis of $V$ defines an orientation, and two bases define the same orientation iff the base change matrix has positive determinant. However, there is no preferred orientation on $V$. So to say your basis is "direct", you have to fix an orientation first. If you are on $\mathbb R^N$, you could take the orientation of the standard basis.

Comment: But if you are on $\mathbb R^N$ with the standard scalar product, you could just take the standard basis anyway... It would also be a good exercise to check if applying the Gram-Schmidt procedure actually changes the orientation of your basis or not.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean by direct: same orientation as the standard basis. I was doing some empirical work projecting trajectories in a 3D basis; the only way for me to get a consistent orientation was with the procedure described in my question; it didn't work with Gram-Schmidt, although to be honest, I would need to double check this...

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. Why is the standard basis not sufficient for whatever you want to do?